# How to use group_by() and case_when() functions in R data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm new to `data.table`, but I understand it may be faster to use in my specific case where I'd like calculate exponentially weighted moving averages with `EMA()` from the `TTR` package.

I have some example data below which is much smaller than my real data set. My current code (which is a bit slow) uses `dplyr` to group by `par` and `cat` as I wish to perform these `EMA()` functions per these variables. If I were to use a `data.table` option, I'm unsure how I would transition the `case_when()` function (and group by two variables) as I'd like the windows for `EMA()` to be different for each level/unique value of `cat`.

Could I please have some help writing the code below for `data.table`? Thanks.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(TTR)
set.seed(0)

par <- rep(paste("Par", 1:5), each = 100)
cat <- rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 100)
val <- rnorm(500, 100, 20)

df <- data.frame(par, cat, val)

new_df <- df %>%
  group_by(par, cat) %>%
  mutate(acute = EMA(val, n = 7, ratio = 2 / (1 + 7))) %>%
  mutate(chron = case_when(
    cat == "A" ~ EMA(val, n = 42, ratio = 2 / (1 + 42)),
    cat == "B" ~ EMA(val, n = 28, ratio = 2 / (1 + 28)),
    cat %in% c("C", "D", "E") ~ EMA(val, n = 14, ratio = 2 / (1 + 14))
  ))
```

Comment: one simple way of doing it would be to use dtplyr, though that is perhaps not what you had in mind

Comment: also instead of `case_when`, `case_match` would be the preferred option I reckon

Comment: *data.table* has a `?fcase` function with very similar syntax that implements SQL-like case/when statements.

Comment: 'Warning messages:
1: There were 5 warnings in `mutate()`.
The first warning was:
ℹ In argument: `acute = EMA(val, n = 7, ratio = 2/(1 + 7))`.
ℹ In group 1: `par = "Par 1"`, `cat = "A"`.
Caused by warning in `EMA()`:
! both 'n' and 'ratio' are specified; using 'n'
ℹ Run `dplyr::last_dplyr_warnings()` to see the 4 remaining warnings.  2: There were 15 warnings in `mutate()`.
The first warning was:
ℹ In argument: `chron = case_when(...)`.
ℹ In group 1: `par = "Par 1"`, `cat = "A"`.
Caused by warning in `EMA()`:
! both 'n' and 'ratio' are specified; using 'n'

Comment: @Ben_89: use [`tidytable`](https://github.com/markfairbanks/tidytable): `tidyverse` syntax with the speed of `data.table`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using compound assignment `` `:=`() `` of *acute* and *chron*, the latter with `ifelse` or, as suggested in comments, `fcase`, data grouped `by=` a `list`.

```
library(data.table); library(TTR)

new_dt <- as.data.table(df)

new_dt[, `:=`(
  acute = EMA(val, ratio=2 / (1 + 7)),
  chron = EMA(val, ratio=2 / (1 + fcase(cat == 'A', 42, cat == 'B', 28, TRUE, 14)))
), by=list(par, cat)]

all.equal(as.data.frame(new_df), as.data.frame(new_dt), check.attributes=F)
# [1] TRUE
```

Note, there was a warning in OP's code, `"both 'n' and 'ratio' are specified; using 'n'"`, so I deleted one of both.

**BTW,** here a benchmark, tested on 3M rows.

```
Unit: milliseconds
       expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq       max neval cld
      dplyr 1454.3974 1577.7288 1656.2631 1701.0603 1757.196 1813.3318     3  a 
 data.table  331.5317  335.9562  449.6939  340.3808  508.775  677.1692     3   b
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(par=rep(paste("Par", 1:5), each=100),
                 cat=rep(LETTERS[1:5], each=100),
                 val=rnorm(500, 100, 20))
```

Answer (score 1):

@jay.sf's answer is the canonical and should be accepted over this one. I offer this only as a commentary on @Mark's suggestion to use `dtplyr`.

In so testing, I found that if we have multiple calls to `EMA` within each return-value inside the `case_when` (translated to `fcase`), then `data.table` is going to fail. This is because the conditional is based on a grouping variable, and grouping variables are always length-1 (see my opened-and-closed [dtplyr#453](https://github.com/tidyverse/dtplyr/issues/453) for the walk-through).

To work around this, we need to adapt jay.sf's alternative where `fcase` is inside the call to `EMA(..)`. In this case, the performance is back to parity with the `dplyr`-native solution.

Demonstration of the direct use, failing:

```r
lazy_dt(df) %>%
  group_by(par, cat) %>%
  mutate(acute = EMA(val, ratio = 2 / (1 + 7))) %>%
  mutate(chron = case_when(
    cat == "A" ~ EMA(val, ratio = 2 / (1 + 42)),
    cat == "B" ~ EMA(val, ratio = 2 / (1 + 28)),
    cat %in% c("C", "D", "E") ~ EMA(val, ratio = 2 / (1 + 14))
  )) %>%
  as_tibble()
# Error in fcase(cat == "A", EMA(val, ratio = 2/(1 + 42)), cat == "B", EMA(val,  : 
#   Length of output value #2 must either be 1 or length of logical condition.
```

Adapting jay.sf's method, though, we get the results we need (same results as `new_df`):

```r
lazy_dt(df) %>%
  group_by(par, cat) %>%
  mutate(acute = EMA(val, ratio = 2 / (1 + 7))) %>%
  mutate(chron = EMA(val, ratio = 2 / (1 + fcase(cat == "A", 42, cat == "B", 28, cat %in% c("C", "D", "E"), 14)))) %>%
  as_tibble()
# # A tibble: 500 × 5
#    par   cat     val acute chron
#    <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 Par 1 A     125.    NA     NA
#  2 Par 1 A      93.5   NA     NA
#  3 Par 1 A     127.    NA     NA
#  4 Par 1 A     125.    NA     NA
#  5 Par 1 A     108.    NA     NA
#  6 Par 1 A      69.2   NA     NA
#  7 Par 1 A      81.4  104.    NA
#  8 Par 1 A      94.1  102.    NA
#  9 Par 1 A      99.9  101.    NA
# 10 Par 1 A     148.   113.    NA
# # ℹ 490 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

And the performance is comparable (though not `data.table`-native fast):

```
bench::mark(
  dplyr = df %>% group_by(par, cat) %>% mutate(acute = EMA(val, ratio = 2 / (1 + 7))) %>% mutate(chron = case_when( cat == "A" ~ EMA(val, ratio = 2 / (1 + 42)), cat == "B" ~ EMA(val, ratio = 2 / (1 + 28)), cat %in% c("C", "D", "E") ~ EMA(val, ratio = 2 / (1 + 14)) )),
  data.table = new_dt[, `:=`( acute = EMA(val, ratio=2 / (1 + 7)), chron = EMA(val, ratio=2 / (1 + fcase(cat == 'A', 42, cat == 'B', 28, TRUE, 14))) ), by=list(par, cat)],
  dtplyr = lazy_dt(df) %>% group_by(par, cat) %>% mutate(acute = EMA(val, ratio = 2 / (1 + 7))) %>% mutate(chron = EMA(val, ratio = 2 / (1 + fcase(cat == "A", 42, cat == "B", 28, cat %in% c("C", "D", "E"), 14)))) %>% as_tibble(),
  check = FALSE
)
# # A tibble: 3 × 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory time             gc                
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list> <list>           <list>            
# 1 dplyr        5.27ms   5.55ms      178.        NA     8.80    81     4      454ms <NULL> <NULL> <bench_tm [85]>  <tibble [85 × 3]> 
# 2 data.table 940.06µs   1.02ms      973.        NA     8.42   462     4      475ms <NULL> <NULL> <bench_tm [466]> <tibble [466 × 3]>
# 3 dtplyr        5.2ms   5.46ms      182.        NA     8.76    83     4      457ms <NULL> <NULL> <bench_tm [87]>  <tibble [87 × 3]>
```

There are two other workaround, both perform slower (~160 `` `itr/sec` ``):

- force each conditional to be the correct length, as in `rep(cat == "A", n())`; or
- duplicate the grouping variable and condition on the ungrouped version, as in `mutate(cat2 = cat, ...)` and `case_when(cat2 == "A" ~ ...)`.